# How to draw chair-form for trans-decalin (with slight variation)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, notation

I understand how to draw chair form for *trans*-decalin (figure 1) for the usual structure, but I am having difficulty if taken as shown in figure 2 wherein the hydrogens at bridge-head carbons are in opposite orientation. Please help me with relevant chair form diagram.

[image: chair-form for trans-decalin]

Comment: See a model kit ([example](https://www.maruzen.info/hgs/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=653), for this type of question a bit too few atoms, though) if **1** and **2** are really different from each other.

Comment: I know that they are identical, since on rotation about an axis perpendicular to the plane of molecular, they are inter-convertible. But if given figure 2, translating it directly to a chair form gives the highly strained trans-decalin as shown in:
https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/08/05/fused-rings/#seven

Comment: In figure 1, when we translate directly to chair form, the top bridgehead carbon can easily have the hydrogen take up the position axially pointing upwards and similarly for bottom bridgehhead hydrogen, thereby making the chair form stable.

Whereas in figure 2, doing the same yields the improbable highly strained conformation. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: @Ritwik_Kumar Since **1** and **2** represent the same molecule (including atomic spatial arrangement in 3D-space) I suspect the question is essentially how to make the illustration for the second viewpoint look better. Is [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89xlp.png) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I was getting the same. Is it a problem that it doesn't look like chair form? I am unable to resolve this mental issue when solving or teaching this type of representation...

Comment: @Ritwik_Kumar Well, one representation is better than the other. In 2D both structures look fine, in 3D not so, and higher dimensions will likely cause more confusion.

Comment: There is no short way to avoid building a 3D model of the two alternatives. Get a kit and build both. And this should clarify that cis-decalin is not "improbable or highly strained". It is less stable than the trans molecule but not by a huge amount mainly because the rings are not locked and can therefore interact a bit spatially in some conformations.

Comment: I did not understand. What is wrong with drawing just the bottom left for both the structures at the top?

Comment: I need to emphasize that I am asking for a solution to paper chemistry (i.e., chemistry done on paper using 2d projections of 3d structures). I am able to visualize that the two are identical and superimposable on rotation. Using kits and models is a solution but our first instinct is to use 2d projections for simple molecules. I want to know if there is a solution to resolve the 2d projection issue I am facing.

Comment: @Alchimista, When we try to convert figure 2 directly (without rotating to figure 1) to chair form projection representation, it will come out as linked by andselisk in a previous comment as a .png

Answer (score 3):

### Use of 3D models

3D version of Figure 1:

[image]

Viewed upside down (rotate about z by 180 degrees):

[image]

Now it looks like we are viewing from the bottom, so we will turn the molecule a bit around the x axis:

[image]

### Use of 2D projections

If you want to use the 2D projections, consider whether hydrogens are pointing up or down on the bridge head. First, we will interpret the chair as viewing the top of the ring from above (left panel) rather than viewing the bottom of the ring from below (right panel) to avoid ambiguity.

[image]

No matter whether you use two fused chairs as drawn by the OP (Fig 1 bottom panel) or its mirror image, the front hydrogen will point down and the back hydrogen will point up. This works well for Fig 1.

In order to use the same chair building block but show the front hydrogen pointing up, you could rotate the flat model, and connect two chairs accordingly, as shown below. In effect, you choose the location of the two bridging position to match the stereochemistry you want.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the 3d models Karsten but I was looking more for a solution in the realm of 2d projections as shown in question. We can use the final 3d structure that you have provided to draw the 2d projection but it looks a bit complicated to teach.

Comment: @Ritwik_Kumar I added a second part to my answer.

Comment: Because the 2D images in the original post are identical, the 3D image shown fits either one. The reason this image is usually drawn is that the methine hydrogens are not visually obscured by other bonds. See Karsten Theis's final two images with methine hydrogens in place.

Answer (score 1):

A common notation in crystallography used for denoting atoms *above* and *below* the plane of the paper for the structures with quasi-flat overall shape is the use of *filled* (⚫) and *open* (⚪) circles, respectively.
I think you can use this technique for decalin as well.
For *trans*-decalin with both rings in chair conformation there is even no need to change your drawing for pseudo-3D (red plane refers to the plane of drawing, not symmetry) (scheme **A**).

Also, note that in crystallography there are also *plus* (+) and *minus* (−) signs used for the same purpose, e.g. denoting an object (including atoms) that lies *above* and *below* the plane containing the reference axes, respectively.
I personally find this notation less applicable here because of the possible confusion arising with the clash of notation for charge distribution (scheme **B**).

[image: depiction of trans-decalin in 2D with inconvenient H-placement point of view]